# Displaying Image from URL in python/Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am working on a weather app and to add some spice I was thinking on adding a Weather Map, so reached over to https://openweathermap.org/api/weathermaps and got a URL with the image. I researched for many methods on displaying that image on a Tkinter Widget but none of them work. It displays the size of the image but not the image itself. This is my code. Thank you very much.

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import requests
import urllib.request
import base64

root = Tk()
root.title("Weather")


link = "https://tile.openweathermap.org/map/pressure_new/0/0/0.png?appid={APIkey}"

class WebImage:
     def __init__(self,url):
          u = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
          raw_data = u.read()
          u.close()
          self.image = PhotoImage(data=base64.encodebytes(raw_data))

     def get(self):
          return self.image

img = WebImage(link_6).get()
imagelab = Label(root, image = img)
imagelab.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You code works fine if the image in the link is PNG.  May be the image in the link is JPEG which is not supported by `tkinter.PhotoImage`.

You can use `Pillow` module which supports various image formats:

```
import tkinter as tk
import urllib.request
#import base64
import io
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Weather")

link = "https://openweathermap.org/themes/openweathermap/assets/img/logo_white_cropped.png"

class WebImage:
    def __init__(self, url):
        with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as u:
            raw_data = u.read()
        #self.image = tk.PhotoImage(data=base64.encodebytes(raw_data))
        image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(raw_data))
        self.image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)

    def get(self):
        return self.image

img = WebImage(link).get()
imagelab = tk.Label(root, image=img)
imagelab.grid(row=0, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It works, although when I insert it all in a function (so I can display the image when a button is pressed) it doesn't work anymore. What should I do?

Comment: It depends on how you implement it in the function.

Comment: I was planning on doing the following:
`
def submit():
     class WebImage:
         def __init__(self, url):
             with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as u:
                 raw_data = u.read()
             image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(raw_data))
             self.image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)

         def get(self):
             return self.image
    img = WebImage(link).get()
    imagelab = tk.Label(root, image=img)
    imagelab.grid(row=1, column=0)

tk.Button(root, text = "Submit", command = submit).grid(row = 0, column = 0)
`

Comment: You need to save a reference of the image: `imagelab.image = img`.

Comment: Where should I add "image.image = img" to my code?

Comment: After `imagelab` is created.

Answer (score 1):

Here try this:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import requests
from io import BytesIO


root = Tk()
root.title("Weather")


link = "yourlink/image.jpg"

class WebImage:
     def __init__(self,url):
          u = requests.get(url)
          self.image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(BytesIO(u.content)))
          
     def get(self):
          return self.image

img = WebImage(link).get()
imagelab = Label(root, image = img)
imagelab.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I tried your code but I got the following error: TypeError: WebImage() takes no arguments. When I take out the argument "link" from WebImage I get this other error: AttributeError: 'WebImage' object has no attribute 'image' . Thank you for your help anyways.

Comment: @LorenzoHsu you might have missed url argument in the `__init__()` method